# Build Landingpages on other domains to not hurt SEO of main business domain?

Tags: seo, cross-domain, event-tracking, third-party-cookies

One week ago, I've posted a question on the [webmasters forum](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/144507/build-landingpages-on-other-domains-to-not-hurt-seo-of-main-domain) which has not even received a single comment. Thinking about it now, the question may be too technical / is inherently related to technical aspects of domains, first- vs third-party cookies, tracking / analytics implementations, identity resolution, etc. So I thought of adding the question here:

I've a new customer who previously worked with a marketing agency who creates landingpages for his marketing campaigns. Imagine the customer's main website running on `example.org`.

The agency creates all their landingpages that serve as target of campaigns on a separate domain, e.g.:

- Instead of running a marketing campaign about medicinal-topic-1 via a landingpage hosted on `example.org/medicinal-topic-1`, they host that landingpage with a brand new installation on `medicinal-topic-1.org`.

Their argumentation is that, if anything is "flagged as bad content" in terms of SEO on `medicinal-topic-1.org`, that it won't affect the ranking on `example.org`.

Besides the obvious downsides of:

- Needing to configure a separate server / server directory for every single landingpage.
- Needing to manage a separate wordpress installation for every single landingpage (which is how they manage the content of their landingpages - massive overkill imho).
- Losing your visitor's trust in your brand when they drop on a somewhat random domain instead of dropping on your `example.org` domain.
- Data Tracking Configurations becoming an absolute mess due to this, especially with the upcoming third-party cookie deprecation (e.g. how to track conversion on your `medicinal-topic-1.org` domain that actually originated from a deep link of `example.org`?)
- Actually not gaining the traffic of your campaigns on your main website.
- and so on....

I wonder if the argumentation of the agency is actually true / makes any sense?

Comment: Webmasters is the correct place to ask.